# Futur vs. avenir?

Tags: usage, sens

Il apparaît que les mots « futur » et « avenir » portent le même sens, mais ils existent tous les deux. Quand doit-on utiliser le premier, et quand le deuxième ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ils sont synonymes.

Pour la plupart du temps, on utilise le mot *futur* quand on parle du temps grammatical, donc *futur* est un terme de grammaire. Pour tous les autres cas, on préfère se servir du mot *avenir*. Il est aussi d'autres cas où l'on pourrait utiliser *futur* et où *futur* convient mieux au contexte, par exemple, quand *futur* est un adjectif, ou pour dire « ce qui sera ».

Voici la remarque qu'a écrit Littré dans son dictionnaire :

> FUTUR, AVENIR. Le futur est ce qui sera ; l'avenir est ce qui
>   adviendra. Ces deux sens se confondent dans l'usage presque toujours :
>   les siècles à venir ou les siècles futurs ne présentent pas d'autre
>   nuance que celle qui est dans la notion même d'être ou de venir. Il
>   n'y a que dans la langue du droit où futur ne peut être remplacé par à
>   venir : les futurs conjoints. On dirait cependant l'héritier à venir
>   aussi bien que le futur héritier.

Answer (score 4):

Les implications de *futur* et *avenir* viennent toutes les deux du latin.

Ce que je comprends, c'est que *futur* en latin implique une série d'évènements qui n'est pas nécessairement **claire** mais qui va **arriver** néanmoins : le mot *futur* est une idée *abstraite* chronologique.

Le mot *avenir* implique quant à lui quelque chose qui va arriver, qui est également *envisageable* et qui se rapporte au présent.

Par exemple :

> Il est promis à un grand *avenir*.
>
> Il se prépare un **futur** qui n'est guère meilleur que le passé.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne crois pas que *futur* et *avenir* portent exactement le même sens, ni ne s'utilisent toujours dans le même contexte. Mais distinguer la différence demande sûrement beaucoup d'habitude. Je pense qu'on parle essentiellement de l'avenir **de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose** :

> C'est l'avenir de nos enfants.
>
> Quel avenir pour le pays ?
>
> Le Minitel n'a pas d'avenir.

Alors qu'on parle du futur comme d'un **concept en soi**, ou bien on l'utilise comme un **qualificatif** :

> Dans le futur, le tourisme spatial sera très répandu.
>
> Le futur simple appartient au mode indicatif.
>
> C'est ma fiancée, ma future femme.

Cependant, on peut aussi utiliser *à venir* pour qualifier quelque chose qui commence immédiatement et s'étend dans le temps :

> On prévoie du beau temps pour les jours à venir.

Ici on parle en quelque sorte de l'avenir du jour présent ! On peut tout aussi bien utiliser les jours *futurs*, mais cela sonne [comme de la poésie](http://www.poesie-francaise.fr/andre-lemoyne/poeme-jours-futurs.php), et ne commence pas aujourd'hui.

L'avenir est aussi un concept, mais mon sentiment est que quand on parle de l'avenir, on parle implicitement de notre avenir, voire de l'avenir de l'humanité ou de la planète :

> On ne sait jamais de quoi l'avenir sera fait.
>
> Les émissions de dioxyde de carbone sont-elles un danger pour l'avenir ?

Il y a aussi des expressions **toutes faites** (idiomatiques ?), comme *à l'avenir*, pour une prédiction ou un désir pour le futur :

> Tu as fait une bêtise. A l'avenir, que ça ne se reproduise plus !

Bref, voilà quelques exemples où l'on distingue les deux mais ils sont souvent interchangeables. Tout comme *power* en anglais peut se traduire soit par *pouvoir*, soit par *puissance*, soit par les deux à la fois.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr d'être d'accord avec les distinctions que vous faites, surtout sans source. La banque de dépannage linguistique a [un article sur le sujet](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2798) qui ne confirme pas entièrement vos impressions. Sur un autre sujet, on écrit "prévoit" avec un _t_ final et non un _e_.

Answer (score 2):

Bien que ce soit un usage tout à fait personnel, je rattache *avenir* à projet, et *futur* au temps.

A projet j'associe ici la notion de nécessité (orientation de l'affect) qui propulse l'humain dans son *avenir* (à venir), avec les déclinaisons qu'en a fait Homère.

Sinon passé, présent, *futur* sont des enfants de Chronos.

Dans un contexte courant, on va voir une cartomancienne pour se faire prédire l'*avenir* parce que l'on cherche à connaître par avance l'orientation que le mouvement du temps va déterminer.

*Le futur sera alors la réalisation d'un des avenirs possibles*.

C'est une question de consonance avec *à venir* : inverser ces deux mots laisse la phrase compréhensible sans en modifier la signification, mais n'est pas naturel.

*Complément* : Le nouveau petit Le Robert semble abonder dans ce sens :

> *futur* 
>   adjectif : 
>    - qui appartient à l'avenir,
>    - qui sera tel dans l'avenir
>   nom : 
>   - Partie du temps qui vient après le présent
>   - *futur* est abusivement utilisé pour *avenir* sous l'influence de l'anglais *future*.

⚠ un exemple fourni à l'entrée *avenir* vient confirmer l'usage abusif : « le passé, le présent et l'avenir », sans annotation ou remarque sur cet abus de langage.

Answer (score 0):

Le futur est la rėalitė du temps qui passera d'une façon inėxorable. L'avenir est une rėalisation de soi, seul ou å travers d'autrui.