# Would this make sense? Dans l'avenir, j'espère d'obtenir de bonnes notes à l'école et de réussir dans la vie

Tags: grammaire

Is my grammar right, have i wrote anything wrong? please tell me because I am trying to learn :-).
Dans l'avenir, j'espère d'obtenir de bonnes notes à l'école et de réussir dans la vie.
I have tried to research about it, but found nothing. I used a dictionary and I'm trying...

Comment: Please visit the the [help centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) and say exactly what is your problem.

Comment: This [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2324/3177) may provide some insight for using _avenir_. It is also valued to describe the research you did when you don't find something. Why not try feeding _in the future_ to [_Collins_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-french) for instance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

" Dans l'avenir, j'espère obtenir de bonnes notes à l'école et réussir dans la vie "

Depending on what you want to tell, " à l'avenir " may be more correct.

You can trust me as I'm french ;)

---

To be more precise ;)

"à l'avenir" has the following connotation: "It hasn't been the case in the past, but from now I will make my best for it to be". = example here: I used to have bad grades, but it is going to change.

"Plus tard" may also be used, it is used towards a time you can't exactly imagine, or at least you haven't reached yet. Example here: I'm not going to school yet, but when it will be the case, I wan't to have some good grades.

Hoping it has been useful :)

Comment: French Language is not a translation service. And by the way, I am French too and does not agree with your sentence in French.

Comment: Bonjour! En quoi n'êtes-vous pas d'accord avec la phrase ci-dessus? Je crois avoir été assez claire. Par ailleurs, il ne s'agit pas ici de traduction, mais de correction. Vos souhaits quant à l'utilisation de ce site sont donc exaucés, au cas où la question de traduction vous dérangerait. Meilleures salutations.

Comment: *In the future* se dit "à l'avenir" en Français, "dans l'avenir" n'est pas correct ici."French Language is not a text translation or proof reading service" I think this is clear enough.

Comment: (by the way... *he/she/it* does not agree, but you **don't* or **do not** !):)

Comment: Quant à "à l'avenir", cela est précisé également. :)

Comment: This website is about the french language, that is why it is called 'French Language'. If you stop people from answering to my question about the 'French Language' then what use is this website, honestly... I really need help, I have translated, and am asking what is wrong with my text, which is about the 'french language' and you say that my question doesn't apply with the website. The website is called the 'french language' for a reason u know... sigh...